# Leaflet popup - Insert image

Tags: leaflet, popup, photos

I want to insert an image in a popup when I click on a layer. I'm successfully using [Leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) but when I want to display an image I've always have `undefined`. My url is stored in a `postgres` database.

```
myLayer.on('click', function(a){
        var match = leafletPip.pointInLayer(a.latlng, myLayer, false);
        if (match.length) {
            popUpText = '';         
            for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
                popUpText += '<div align="center"><b>';                 
                popUpText += match[i].feature.properties.name + '</b></div><br>';
                popUpText += '<div align="center">' + match[i].feature.properties.photo + '</div><br>';             
            popUpText += '';
            }
        }
        var popup = L.popup().setLatLng(a.latlng).setContent(popUpText).openOn(map);
});
```

My field `photo` looks like this

```
'<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg" height="150px" width="150px"/>'
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of the formatting just using an on-click, Note the popup is already a div, so you don't really need more divs in it.

```
var popup = L.popup();

var photoImg = '<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg" height="150px" width="150px"/>';

function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("<center>My Photo </center>" + "</br>"+ photoImg)
        .openOn(mymap);
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Comment: Ok with this but in my case, each feature have is own image, stored on in a field `feature.properties.photo`, a static div can't be the answer. Furthermore leaflet-pip alows to find overlays polygons with `match[i]`.

Comment: I use photoImg as the value for  match[i].feature.properties.photo, Either should work. I would use console.log(match[i].feature.properties.photo) to make sure your photos are being defined.  If they are this should work.                                           One of my internal pulls pictures for popup this way. '<img src="' +e.target.feature.properties.Picture +'" style="width:auto; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;">';

Comment: Why not `var photoImg = '<img src="'+match[i].feature.properties.photo +'" style="width:auto; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;">';` ? `console.log(match[i].feature.properties.photo);` returns me `TypeError: match[i] is undefined`

Comment: Stepping back a second, you have a poly layer (myLayer) and you want an image in a popup. Normally this is defined in the layers onEach function as a normal popup. However this looks like you have a layer with overlapping polygons and you are using the pip plugin to open a popup for each of the overlapping polygons in that layer?  If pip is not returning the photo I would expect it's also not returning the name and it's really a pip issue not a photo display. Can you clear this up for me?

Comment: You enlightened me : pip is ok but I forgot to call the field photo in my sql querie when I create the layer. Now it works great.